# New CMOS battery - Windows boot not possible - specific external hard drive

Tags: windows-8.1, bios, external-hard-drive, battery

My CMOS battery has run out in my MSI H81M-E34 today and I replaced the old 3V CR 2032 battery with a new 3V CR 2016.
I always had several external hard drives connected with usb 3.0 cables at my usb 3 ports.

Now there is the problem that booting into Windows OS is only possible when I disconnect my external Seagate Portable 5TB drive - otherwise the message 'operating system not found' appears.

What should I try first to fix this issue? Reset specific parameters in Bios?

Comment: Replacing the battery has reset all BIOS settings. You have to restore the USB and boot order configuration in BIOS as it was before. I would start in BIOS by "load optimized default" or a similar command.

Comment: You also have to set the correct date and time in the bios after a battery change for windows to boot.